# How to select into (new table) FROM two joined tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to select two joined tables in the form of CTe into new table?

```
SELECT * 
INTO --new table--
FROM --table below--


WITH AA AS (  
   SELECT DISTINCT[Loyalty_Number], SUM ([Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax]) AS TRANSACTAMOUNT, Trans_Det_Qty AS QTY
   FROM CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
   WHERE Brand = 'Jelly Bunny'
    AND Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date between '2019-01-01'AND '2019-08-31'
    AND Loyalty_Number LIKE 'LM000%'
   GROUP BY Loyalty_Number, Trans_Det_Qty
),
BB AS (
SELECT DISTINCT [Loyalty Card Number], [Person DOB]
FROM CRM_DB_Person
)
SELECT AA.Loyalty_Number , AA.QTY, AA.TRANSACTAMOUNT , BB.[Person DOB]
FROM AA
INNER JOIN BB
ON AA.Loyalty_Number = BB.[Loyalty Card Number]
GROUP BY Loyalty_Number, AA.QTY, AA.TRANSACTAMOUNT, BB.[Person DOB]
```

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: how about adding additiona cte CC?

Comment: yes it did. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create your new table first then add `insert` statement before the last `select` query

```
WITH AA AS (  
   SELECT DISTINCT[Loyalty_Number], SUM ([Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax]) AS TRANSACTAMOUNT, Trans_Det_Qty AS QTY
   FROM CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
   WHERE Brand = 'Jelly Bunny'
    AND Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date between '2019-01-01'AND '2019-08-31'
    AND Loyalty_Number LIKE 'LM000%'
   GROUP BY Loyalty_Number, Trans_Det_Qty
),
BB AS (
SELECT DISTINCT [Loyalty Card Number], [Person DOB]
FROM CRM_DB_Person
)
insert into YourNewTable(Loyalty_Number , QTY, AA.TRANSACTAMOUNT , [Person DOB])
SELECT AA.Loyalty_Number , AA.QTY, AA.TRANSACTAMOUNT , BB.[Person DOB]
--into YourNewTable --you can do this as well, but not a fan of this approach
FROM AA
INNER JOIN BB
ON AA.Loyalty_Number = BB.[Loyalty Card Number]
GROUP BY Loyalty_Number, AA.QTY, AA.TRANSACTAMOUNT, BB.[Person DOB]
```

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: @NorNorranun Then you can mark it as answer by selecting the tick mark present in the left of this answer.